# How to chain Promises and callback-style code

Tags: javascript, promise, return

I'm confused on how this chaining for promises work, I'm still fairly new to promises and js in general so excuse me

line three,   `return user.findOne({email}).then((user) => {`, i'm just confused about how returning this promise does anything since it returns a other promise inside the .then()

```
UserSchema.statics.findByCredentials = function(email, password){
  user = this;
  return user.findOne({email}).then((user) => {
      if (!user){
        return Promise.reject();
      }
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, res) => {
          if (res){
            resolve(user);
          }else{
            reject()
          }
        });
    });

  });
}
```

the findByCredentials model method being used in an express app

```
app.post("/users/login", (req, res) => {
  var body = _.pick(req.body, ["email", "password"]);
  User.findByCredentials(body.email, body.password).then((user) => {
    res.send(body)
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.send("!");
  })
```

A simpler example I just created, this part

> return plus(1).then((res) => {
>
> > return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
> >     is the problem i'm having trouble understanding

```
function plus(a) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(a + 1);
  });
}

function test() {
  return plus(1).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve("Test");
    });
  });
}

test().then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Returning promises from `then` callbacks is [the true power of promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi Hate to bother you but you're the expert; Would you write this in another way, different than the one I've described in my answer? I'm curious to know as well.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides you mean the explanation or the code? Regarding the code, I would not have used `new Promise` as [`bcrypt` natively supports returning promises](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#with-promises) :-)

Comment: @Bergi Nice; I'll add it as a comment but keep the structure as-is to illustrate how to handle callback-style code in a Promise chain.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Actually I really liked the original revision of your answer where you had factored it out into a helper function. Makes promise code much more readable imo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Bergi said in the comment of your OP, the true power or `Promises` comes from returning them in the `then` of other `Promises`.

- This allows you to *chain* Promises in a clean way.
- To chain Promises all your operations in the chain *must* be Promises.
- Your `bcrypt.compare` function uses callbacks to signal that it's done, so you need that function convert to a `Promise`.

This is easy to do. Just wrap the callback-style code in a Promise and `resolve` the `result` of the callback or `reject` if the callback is called with an `err`.

```
const comparePassword = (a, b) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    bcrypt.compare(a, b, (err, result) => {
      // Reject if there was an error
      // - rejection is `return`-ed solely for stopping further execution
      //   of this callback. No other reason for it.
      if (err) return reject(err)

      // Resolve if not.
      resolve(result)
    })
  })   
}
```

... and then we can chain properly:

```
UserSchema.statics.findByCredentials = function(email, password) {
  // Outer Promise: 
  // - Will eventually resolve with whatever the result it's inner
  //   promise resolves with.
  return user.findOne({ email })
    .then((user) => {
      // Inner Promise: 
      // - Will eventually resolve with `user` (which is already
      //   available here), given that the password was correct, 
      //   or 
      //   reject with the bcrypt.compare `err` if the password was 
      //   incorrect. 
      return comparePassword(password, user.password)
        .then((result) => {
          // This `then` belongs to the comparePassword Promise.
          // - We use this so we can make sure we return the `user` we picked up
          //   from the previous `user.findOne` Promise.
          // - This ensures that when you chain a `then` to this Promise chain
          //   you always get the `user` and not the result of `comparePassword`
          return user
        })
    })
}
```

The key here is that whatever you `return` within a `.then()` is going to be passed as an argument to the next chained `.then()`.

#### Additional info:

- `bcrypt.compare` [already returns a `Promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#with-promises), so we could have avoided the whole hassle of wrapping it into a Promise. I've intentionally used it with callbacks to illustrate how you should handle callback-style code in a Promise chain.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make my intentions clear, i'm not really looking for a fix, more of an explanation of why/how it works

Comment: And you would be correct to do that; Let me edit and explain. My bad.

Comment: I added a simpler example to work off of if it'd be easier for you to answer